# How do I get my data to show up in my ALV?

Tags: abap, alv

I'm thinking that I'm probably missing an export parameter (from my Function Call POV).

In the `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY` function call, the parameters I pass around are:
Exporting:

```
   i_callback_program,
   i_callback_pf_status_set,
   i_callback_user_command,
   is_layout,
   it_fieldcat,
   i_save
Tables:
   t_outtab
```

And the exceptions plus handling.

I've checked that the internal table that I pass has data and it does.

I think the information I put up will suffice but if you really need to see the code, I'll do so.

I'm a noob and any help would be appreciated.

Thanx.

Comment: What function module are you calling?

Comment: You should always provide some sample code if possible, that would have made answering a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to use ALV, so we may indeed need more info on your code to help.

- First Method is to use the function module REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY. This will directly display the table content in the output dynpro. If all you need is a display, then go for it, as this is the simpliest : If the table structure is in the dictionnary, this call can be as simple as the following (this will display all members of the struct as column)

> 

```
myreport = sy-repid.
CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
      EXPORTING
          i_callback_program          = myreport
          it_excluding                = exclude_tab
       TABLES
          t_outtab                    = display_data
       EXCEPTIONS
          program_error               = 1
          OTHERS                      = 2.
```

If the structure is declared in the program, then you have to create a field catalog.
the following code can serve as basis :

```
FORM fill_fieldcat CHANGING p_fieldcat   TYPE slis_t_fieldcat_alv.

* Data definition
  DATA ls_fieldcat  TYPE slis_fieldcat_alv.

* Macro definition
  DEFINE append_fieldcat.
    clear ls_fieldcat.

    ls_fieldcat-fieldname      = &1. * name of the field in struct
    ls_fieldcat-tabname        = &2. * name of the table
    ls_fieldcat-row_pos        = &3. * column
    ls_fieldcat-ref_fieldname  = &4. * field in ref table
    ls_fieldcat-ref_tabname    = &5. * ref table
    ls_fieldcat-outputlen      = &6. * size of output
    ls_fieldcat-seltext_m      = &7. * text (space if using the element typetext)
    ls_fieldcat-ddictxt        = 'M'.
    ls_fieldcat-key            = &8.  * is this a key field in table
    ls_fieldcat-emphasize      = &9.  * emphisze  column display

    append ls_fieldcat to p_fieldcat.
  END-OF-DEFINITION.

* Init.
  REFRESH p_fieldcat.

* Append fielcatalog for ALV
  append_fieldcat:
  'FORMATIONCODE' 'DISPLAY_TAB' 1 'SHORT' 'HRP1000' 12    'Code Stage'     space space,
  'FORMATIONTEXT' 'DISPLAY_TAB' 1 'STEXT' 'HRP1000' 20    'Libelle Stage'  space space,
  'SESSIONID'     'DISPLAY_TAB' 1 'OBJID' 'HRP1000' space 'Session'        space space,
  'BEGDA'         'DISPLAY_TAB' 1 'BEGDA' 'HRP1000' space 'Debut'          space space,
  'ENDDA'         'DISPLAY_TAB' 1 'BEGDA' 'HRP1000' space 'Fin'            space space,
ENDFORM.                    "fill_fieldCat
```

you then call the form to create the field catalog, and use it in the it_fieldcat parameter of the function call.

- Second method is to use ABAP-Object. Use check se83 for exemples of this use. the basis is as follows :

In your Dynpro you declare a custom container with a given name ("ALV_CONT"). Then in then PBO of the dynpro you initialize the container and put an ALV objct inside :

```
* global variables :
DATA : delegationlist_table     TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid,
       delegationlist_container TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container.
data : gs_layout   TYPE lvc_s_layo.
```

in PBO

```
  IF delegationlist_container IS INITIAL.
*   create a custom container control for our ALV Control
    CREATE OBJECT delegationlist_container
      EXPORTING
        container_name              = 'ALV_CONT'
      EXCEPTIONS
        cntl_error                  = 1
        cntl_system_error           = 2
        create_error                = 3
        lifetime_error              = 4
        lifetime_dynpro_dynpro_link = 5.

*   create an instance of alv control
    CREATE OBJECT delegationlist_table
      EXPORTING
        i_parent = delegationlist_container.

*   Set a titlebar for the grid control
    gs_layout-grid_title = 'Délégations'.
    gs_layout-sel_mode = 'A'.
    gs_layout-cwidth_opt ='X'.

*   set table as data source
*   the struct name *must* be uppercase
*   the table must have this struc
    CALL METHOD delegationlist_table->set_table_for_first_display
      EXPORTING
        i_structure_name = 'ZPRT_DELEGATIONLIST'
        is_layout        = gs_layout
      CHANGING
        it_outtab        = delegationlist.

  ENDIF.
```

Hopes this help,
Regards

Guillaume PATRY

Comment: Three comments to this: 1. myrepid is no longer necessary in current R/3 versions (see the ABAP release notes on SY-REPID). 2. I'd recommend using REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY_LVC, it does the same thing but with more current parameter structures. 3. Never create the field catalog manually if you can avoid it - you're likely to forget to adapt your program if you change the underlying structure later.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Oh, and another thing - if you're really in POV (process on Value-Request = F4), be aware that there are limitations to what you can do. Try your code in a simple report right after START-OF-SELECTION, and if that works, try the same code in a POV module.

===

If you don't pass a structure name, you have to ensure that you pass a complete (!) field catalog, otherwise the ALV grid might start to work erratically or not at all. Use the function modules LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE and LVC_FIELDCAT_COMPLETE (in this order) to get a LVC field catalog that can be used with the classes or REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY_LVC.

Answer (score 1):

A couple people here suggested using the REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY. I'm sure this is a common way to get things done (I used to use it myself), but I've taken a sap delta course recently and they strongly suggested to not use it anymore (you can look it up, REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY is not officialy supported by SAP anymore).

Instead, use CL_SALV_TABLE, documentation here: http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/EN/d7/b22041aa7df323e10000000a155106/frameset.htm

It's actually rather convenient to use too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the effort but as it turned out, the mistake I did was that I didn't capitalize field names in building the Field Catalog. Such a newbie mistake. I guess I won't be doing that mistake again any time soon.

-migs

Answer (score 0):

Pass the output internal table to the FM Parameter "t_outtab".
It will print your data output.